# itemController in ArrayController vs #each

Tags: ember.js

Following along with the [Getting Started Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/display-a-button-to-remove-completed-todos/) I have this http://jsbin.com/enutit/2/edit

My question is how come I can't remove the itemController from this each helper

```
<ul id="todo-list">
    {{#each controller itemController="todo"}}
        <li {{bindAttr class="isCompleted:completed isEditing:editing"}}>
```

and then add

```
itemController: 'todo',
```

to Todos.TodosController and have it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the controller's properties are not the same as the `{{each}}` helper's properties.

`{{each}}` internally creates an instance of `Ember.Handlebars.EachView` to display each item in the `Todos.TodosController`'s `content` property. It is this view that needs the `itemController` property so that it can create a new `Todos.TodoController` (note the singular form) instance for each child view.

Comment: Sellund, but removing the itemController from the each helper, and adding in the TodosController does work, http://jsbin.com/urakoc/1/edit

Comment: Hyder, not quite, if you try to edit one of those items, you can't nor can you clear completed. It throws errors because it can't find the controller for the item you clicked.